# Determining rates in an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling, biology

I am building a model with a system of ODEs for the interaction of bacteria with human cells.

I want to determine the rate parameters in the model and in the literature I found that the maximum number of bacteria that can get attached to a single cell is 20 and this maximum number will be reached within 4 hours. 
I want to know how I can use these information to come up with the rates that I want.

In the model I have a rate with which unattached bacteria gets attached. As it takes 4 hours for 20 bacteria to attach, can I take the rate with which a bacterium moves to the attached state to be 4/20?

Then I have another rate, namely the rate with which cells move into the infected cell stage. This happens when a cell can no longer attach any more bacteria (having reached its maximum capacity for attachment) is reached. So, can I take it to be 1/4 hours?

My model is somewhat similar to the model found [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21300073) (the rate with which cells become infected in my model is modelled similarly to the rate $\omega$; $P$ is the bacteria, $E_A$ is the uninfected cells, $E_U$ is the infected cells):

[image]

Comment: @Harry49 Intuitively I want the rate with which unattached bacteria gets attached to be much lower than cells move into the infected cell stage. But what do you mean by assuming constant? Although there can be a relationship between these two rates I don't know exactly what thst is and how to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the model I have a rate in which unattached bacteria gets attached. As it takes 4 hours for 20 bacteria to attach, can I take the rate that a bacteria moves to attached state be 4/20.

That strongly depends on how the attachment works. Consider the following mechanisms of attachment:

1. There is a big reservoir of mostly randomly moving bacteria.
   Whenever a bacterium is in the vicinity of a cell that is not yet covered with bacteria, it will seek out a free space and become attached to the cell.
   In this case, your model would make sense as the 4 hours in question are determined only by how long it statistically takes for 20 bacteria to come within the vicinity of the cell.
   A differential equation that models the number of bacteria $n$ attached to a single cell would be:

   $$\frac{\mathrm{d} n}{\mathrm{d} t} = \frac{20}{4\,\mathrm{h}} = 5 \,{\mathrm{h}}^{-1}$$
2. There is a big reservoir of randomly moving bacteria.
   When a bacterium collides *directly* with a cell, it “sticks”.
   Twenty bacteria fully cover a cell such that there is no way another bacterium can directly collide with the cell (it can only hit other bacteria).
   In this case, your model is not accurate, as the more bacteria are already attached to a cell, the less likely it is for another one to hit a free spot and become attached.

   Instead you would the number of bacteria $n$ attached to a single cell to behave roughly exponentially over time, for instance: $n=20·(1-\exp(-ρt))$.
   The corresponding differential equation could be something like $$\frac{\mathrm{d} n}{\mathrm{d} t} = ρ·(20-n).$$
   (Note that $ρ=\frac{1}{\mathrm{h}}$ roughly matches your observations.)

The model you quote suggest something along the lines of option 2. However, things are a bit different:

- There is no infinite reservoir of bacteria.
- It’s a population model and not a model for a single cell.
- There are other things going on which I can only understand with studying the paper.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have the differential equation as ${dB\over dt}=rate*B*C$  where B is bacteria and C is uninfected cell. The equation of change of infected cells is similar, and the only difference is the rate where I expect much lower rate than to the bacteria equation.

Comment: Thanks for answering this question. So,when looking for the value of `rate` parameter I found a figure in an article which has plotted number of bacteria per **10** cells over time. There were four data points and I fitted a function of the form $a (1-exp(-\rho t))$ and found values for `a` and $\rho$. The differential equation I have in the model is of the form ${dB\over dt}=rate*B*C$ where B is bacteria and C is uninfected cell. I would appreciate your help to clarify two things. First, whether I should divide $\rho$ by $C$ as in the differential equation I am multiplying by it

Comment: This is continuation of the previous comment. So, my second question is, because the figure in the article has plotted bacteria per **10** cells, I am not sure if the values I obtain for `a` and $\rho $ should be divided by 10, before I use them in the model. It would be a great help if you can help me to clarify this.Thanks

Comment: Please do not ask a follow-up question as a comment. Before you ask your question, please clarify or consider: 1) What exactly is the data you used for your fit? Is this information about a population or about individual bacteria? 2) Assuming that *rate* is constant, your fitted function does not match your differential equation. 3) Please figure out all the assumptions going into your model, in particular about which populations can be seen as reservoirs (i.e., the process in question doesn’t affect them) and how the attachment process works.